# Search query variables escaping

Tags: search, search-query

Search queries allow to filter by the current web property value with the "{Site.propertyName}" syntax (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj683123(v=office.15))

How can be escaped the special characters in the property name?

Ex. my propertyName contains dots and the following syntax is not working:{Site.my.property.name}

Answer (score 0):

use it under `<CDATA>` tag. See the example below. you can use it form your XML in a proper way

```
<![CDATA[
Within this Character Data block I can
use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &, ', and ")
*and* %MyParamEntity; will be expanded to the text
"Has been expanded" ... however, I can't use
the CEND sequence (if I need to use it I must escape one of the
brackets or the greater-than sign).
]]>
```